# "Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body" - Error while accessing json file from S3 bucket using pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to load a large (larger than my system memory) json from s3 bucket to spark Dataframe. but getting below error.

> org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of
> Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 138345560; received:
> 67924532

1. I am using spark 2.4.7 and Hadoop 2.7 distribution, with python 3.7.
2. I have copied "hadoop-aws:2.7.3.jar" & "aws-sdk:1.7.4.jar" in
3. Sparkhome/jars/ directory. Using JDK 1.8 (set SPARK_HOME, JAVA_HOME,
   HADOOP_HOME) environment variables already.
4. previously had python 3.8, java 15, spark 3.0 with hadoop 2.7 - downgraded because of this error.

```
# pyspark_job.py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def create_spark_session():
    """
    Create spark session.
    Returns:
        spark (SparkSession) - spark session
    """
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .master("local[4]") \
        .appName("Myappname") \
        .getOrCreate()
    return spark

def setConfigs(spark):
    """
    setting the environment configuration properties for s3 access
    arguments:
        spark (SparkSession) - spark session
    """
    ak = 'accesskey'    # as of now I am using the keys directly, once i get the basic functionality working, the keys will be taken from property file/env variable
    sk = 'secretkey'
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key",  ak)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", sk)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.readahead.range", '512M')

def process_events_data(spark, input_path):
    """Process the event data from s3 bucket as json files and get specific info.
    Arguments:
        spark (SparkSession) - spark session connected to local cluster
        input_path (str) - AWS S3 bucket path for source data
    returns
        Data Frame with event data
    """
    df = spark.read.format('json').load(input_path)
    #df = spark.read.json("input_path")
    return df
    

def main():
    bn = 'bucketname'
    sf = 'prefix/'
    fp = bn+sf
    input_path = 's3a://bucketname/prefix/filename.json'
    
    spark = create_spark_session()
    setConfigs(spark)
   
    edf = process_events_data(spark, input_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Error trace:**

> 20/09/29 22:32:35 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID
> 1, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled) Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File "pyspark_job.py", line 61, in 
> main()   File "pyspark_job.py", line 58, in main
> process_events_data(spark, input_path)   File "pyspark_job.py", line 41, in process_events_data
> df = spark.read.format('json').load(input_path)   File "spark_dir\spark-2.4.7_h2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py",
> line 166, in load   File
> "spark_dir\spark-2.4.7_h2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py",
> line 1257, in **call**   File
> "spark_dir\spark-2.4.7_h2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py",
> line 63, in deco   File
> "spark_dir\spark-2.4.7_h2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py",
> line 328, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
> occurred while calling o42.load. : org.apache.spark.SparkException:
> Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times,
> most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost,
> executor driver): org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature
> end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 138345560;
> received: 71284276

already tried below solutions but still getting the error:
[Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body SparkException while reading from S3 using Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62788833/premature-end-of-content-length-delimited-message-body-sparkexception-while-read)

I am not sure if some configuration is missing? or something wrong on S3 side? or do i need to read the json input line by line?
This is my first spark program, can anyone help.

Comment: any luck? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: any luck? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: same problem. tried different combinations but still same error.

Comment: any luck? I'm having the same problem.